# Using jQuery to append as sibling rather than child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't seem to find the functionality that I'm looking for. I need to append some DOM elements, as siblings, to a disconnected node.

Seems pretty straight forward, and according to the jQuery documentation I should be able to do this with either .after() or .add(), but neither word:

```
var $set = $('<div class="parent"></div>');
    $set.add('<div class="child"></div>');
    $set.add('<div class="child"></div>');
    $set.add('<div class="child"></div>');
$('body').append($set);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kh9Uj/17/ and http://jsfiddle.net/kh9Uj/19/

It works if I chain them using .add():

```
$('<div class="parent"></div>')
    .add('<div class="child"></div>')
    .add('<div class="child"></div>')
    .add('<div class="child"></div>')
.appendTo('body');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kh9Uj/23/

But not with .after(), and in my application I don't have the option on chaining them. How can I do this?

Edited to fix class / id issue.

Comment: You cannot have duplicate id's, that will cause wonky behavior. Having said that, you're going about it wrong. You're not building a set of children this way, so when you test $set at the end what does it return? Have a look at this - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/kh9Uj/5/

Comment: `$('<div id="child"></div>').appendTo($set);` or `$set.append('<div id="child"></div>');`. And use a `class` instead.

Comment: jQuery `add` simply adds another jQuery object to a jQuery object (like appending a list to a list). The *returned value* of `add` is the combined collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set does not update the variable

```
var $set = $('<div id="parent">0</div>');
$set = $set.add('<div id="child1">1</div>');
$set = $set.add('<div id="child2">2</div>');
$set = $set.add('<div id="child3">3</div>');
$('body').append($set);
```

Chaining works because you are adding them to the same object.

```
var $set = $('<div id="parent">0</div>')          //first element
               .add('<div id="child1">1</div>')   //second element in object
               .add('<div id="child2">2</div>')   //third
               .add('<div id="child3">3</div>');  //fourth
$('body').append($set);
```

BUT add is not adding it to parent. It is adding it as "*siblings*" when you append it.

```
<parent />
<child1 />
<child2 />
<child3 />
```

If you want the "child" elements to be children of "parent" you need to use append.

```
var $set = $('<div id="parent">0</div>');
$set.append('<div id="child1">1</div>');
$set.append('<div id="child2">2</div>');
$set.append('<div id="child3">3</div>');
$('body').append($set);
```

which results in

```
<parent>
    <child1 />
    <child2 />
    <child3 />
</parent>
```